# Ubuntu - Failed logging attempts on blocked ports (SSH doesn't listen on those ports)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, ufw

I'm checking out the failed logging attempts of sshd. To my surprise, I see random ports and being processed by sshd.

First, sshd doesn't even listen on those ports, why does sshd process those requests?

Second, I have ufw enabled (see screenshot). I tried to connect on the random ports but I'm getting a timeout as it should be (ports are blocked).

I don't consider myself an expert but... I thought I was covered. What is going on?

Distro and version: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

UFW status:

[image: UFW]

auth.log:
[image: Failed logging attempts on ports]

Comment: 1) Don't post text output as screenshots. 2) your ufw output doesn't show which ports are allowed 3) ports in auth.log are remote ports, not your local ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my surprise, I see random ports and being processed by sshd.

These are not `sshd` ports, but the client ports (each TCP connection has two ip and port pairs). The message clearly says

> Failed ... **from** IP, port

There is nothing wrong on that. Clients just connect from random ports.